# php form posting trademark, register, copy and utf8 characters

Tags: php, forms, utf-8, codeigniter-2, entities

Trying to figure out why in a php form using the CodeIgniter 2.1.0 I have values being posted to a controller that aren't transposed correctly. 
I can copy in utf8 characters from the form post and insert into my db tables no problem.

I have a problem with things like trademark tags and the register tag.
These tags (both html entity and html numeric) bomb on the reverse end of the form processing, however chinese (simplified HK) work no problem and transpose correctly.

doc type has utf8 in header. I get the wonderful diamond with the question mark.
I've juggled some code (htmlentities,html_entity_decode), and can either get the trademark to reveal itself, or the register mark, but neither both. (Chinese characters, and accented English work fine too). I can't even match the characters on the reverse end in order to do a simple str_replace.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this parameter in your form tag

```
accept-charset="utf-8"
```

You can also use `form_open()` from the form helper which will handle that for you.